# How to make a bot delete its own message after 5 seconds

Tags: discord.py

I can't get the bot to delete its own message.

I have tried await `ctx.message.delete()` and `ctx.message.delete(embed)`

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="List of commands.", description="", colour=discord.Color.orange(), url="")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.delete()
```

I'm wanting the bot to delete the command then send an embed: "A list of commands has been sent to your DM's" then wait 5 secs and delete the embed

Answer (score 4):

`ctx.message.delete()` deletes the message from the user.

But to delete the bot's message you need the bot's message object 
from the `return` of `ctx.send()` :

---

```python
bot.remove_command('help') # Removes default help command 

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="List of commands.", description="", colour=discord.Color.orange())
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed) # Get bot's message

    await ctx.message.delete() # Delete user's message
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    await msg.delete() # Delete bot's message
```

---

**EDIT**:
You can use parameter `delete_after=`(float)

```python
await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5.0)
```